# How do I get Angular to reload the same page but with a different argument?

Tags: html, angular

I have a single Angular component, ProductComponent. Based on the link that is selected as shown in the nav links below, I want the same ProductComponent to be reloaded but with a different parameter. [routerLink]="['/product', 'chicken']", for example, should load the product page but with chicken as the product.

```
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/product', 'chicken']">
    Chicken<br>
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/product', 'salads']">
        Salads<br>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/product', 'sides']">
    Sides<br>
    </a>
</li>
```

The problem is when I am already on the product page, Angular is not reloading the page when a link is clicked because, despite the different parameters, it sees the page, /product,  as already loaded so it does not reload it. How do I solve this.

Comment: Add your `routing.ts`

Comment: when productType changes, you need to fetch data based on the productType and rebind to the component. No need to reload.  Second , instead of using [routerLink], use (click) event handler and pass the appropriate data. That is the right approach to tackel this type of use-cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (courtesy of Mihail C.) is to trick the router into believing its last link was not loaded.

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
      return false;
    }

    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.router.navigated = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `params` in `ActivatedRoute` to fetch the route parameters from the url and then call your function to load the view.

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  public product :any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe((param:Params) => {
       this.product = params['product']; // where product the key defined in route
       // Then call function to update view with new params product
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by subscribing to changes in your route params. You can make use of the observables present in `ActivatedRoute`.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  public product: any;
  constructor (
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.product = params['product'];  // If your route path is 'product/:product'
      // Do something with the new route params. (Eg. Update component state, etc.)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your (Product) component, specify that route reuse should be avoided:

```
constructor(
  public router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```